# Redirect - Even though redirect code is absolute its handled as relative

Tags: redirects, tags, redirection

On my search results page I am testing to see if there is only one result and if so redirecting the user to that result page using the redirect tag.

However, even though the path I am redirecting to is absolute it seems to be handled as relative.

For example - the path I am redirecting to:

```
http://myurl.com/path/to/page
```

Once the redirect is complete the address bar shows:

```
http://myurl.com/http://myurl.com/path/to/page
```

This does still show the right page content, but clearly isn't the right URL.

The code i am using is:

```
{redirect="{url_title_path='store/product'}"}.
```

When placed into a template alone {url_title_path='store/product'} writes out myurl.com/path/to/page and indeed this very same tag works perfectly when applied to an anchor (a) tag.

Any advise on how to resolve this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you shouldn't add the domain on [redirect global variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#redirect).

```
{redirect='template_group/template_or_segment_2'}
```

So, your option is to try:

```
{redirect='store/product/{url_title}'}
```

I have to confess that I never tried to use three segments on redirect global variable.

Comment: Thanks Robson, I haven't manually entered the domain. I am using the following code: {redirect="{url_title_path='store/product'}"}. When placed into a template alone {url_title_path='store/product'} writes out http://myurl.com/path/to/page and indeed this very same tag works perfectly when applied to an anchor (a) tag.

Comment: Please, edit your question to inform this. I gonna update my answer.

Comment: Cheers Robson, I have updated my question.

Comment: Please, mark the right answer.

Comment: Hi Robson... I"m not sure that I have had a correct answer yet!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the RedirectURL plug-in from Rodrigo Passos. It allows you to specify an entire absolute URL.

This would allow you to provide a URL in something like this: `{exp:redirecturl url=“http://myurl.com/{channel_short_name}/{url_title}”}`

Or if you're using page URIs: `{exp:redirecturl url=“http://myurl.com{page_uri}”}`

[Find more information about RedirectURL on Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/redirecturl-ee2-plugin).

Doing this though, you may want to wrap your conditional in a `{exp:ifelse}` tag [using Croxton's IfElse plug-in](https://github.com/croxton/Ifelse). That way you can [be sure your condition isn't parsed after the plugin has already run](http://johndwells.com/blog/expressionengine-parse-order-advanced-conditionals-as-tag-parameters).

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer - and I may well resort to doing it this way, but this surely must be possible without resorting to another plugin?